# how to get property value that is initialized in shell page to controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have initialized a property in shell page(index.html) and i would like to get that value in controller that is called through route.my code is as below

**index.html:**

```
    <html>
    //loaded all libraries,modules
    <ng-init="status=false"></ng-init>
    <ng-init="activator=[{'orders':'active'},{'customers':''},{'about':''}]"></ng-init>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist" ng-show="status">
    <li class="activator.orders"><a href="#customers">Customers</a></li>
    <li class="activator.customers"><a href="#orders">Orders</a></li>
    <li class="activator.about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>

<ng-view></ng-view>

</html>
```

**orderscontroller.js**

```
app.controller('ordersctrl',function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$cookies,$cookieStore,$location)
{
$rootScope.status="true";
$rootScope.myname=$cookieStore.get('name');
alert($rootScope.activator);  //it prints "undefined"
});
```

**customermanager.js**

```
var app=angular.module('customermanager',['ngRoute','ngCookies','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($routeProvider)
           {

    $routeProvider.when('/',
                        {

     controller:'loginctrl',
     templateUrl:'views/loginview.html'

    })
    .when('/orders',
                        {

     controller:'ordersctrl',
     templateUrl:'views/ordersview.html'

    })
    .when('/customers',
                        {

     controller:'customersctrl',
     templateUrl:'views/customersview.html'

    })
     .when('/about',
                        {

     controller:'aboutctrl',
     templateUrl:'views/aboutview.html'

    })
    .otherwise(
        {
         redirectTo:'/' 

        });

});
```

When i click on "#orders", orderscontroller.js and its associated view is called.My requirement is to pass the 'activator' property to orderscontroller.js,please help...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `ngInit` directive has a property: `restrict: 'AC'` which means creating `<ng-init/>` elements won't work.

What is more `ngInit` "allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope" (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). So, if you want to initialize values in the HTML you should do it inside a controller's "scope", that is you should use `ngController` directive and corresponding `ngInit` directives inside it.

```
<div ng-controller="ordersctrl">
    <span ng-init="..." />
    ...
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-controller="ordersctrl" ng-init="...">...</div>
```

I think, you should be also able to this inside `ng-app` (try to add it to you `<html>` tag).

But it is still not elegant, at least. Why do you want to initialize your variables inside HTML? You can assign those values in you controller when you define them just like you did with `$rootScope.status`.

Comment: I am using "angular routes" to map views and controllers...and the property "activator" i need to get is in the shell page(index.html) and i want that property to be accessed in any controller i call.I have updated my code.Hope it is clear.

Comment: Try to change `ng-init` to attribute of some node.